# What is はこう from はこうやって?

Tags: words, meaning

What is the translation of はこう ? (from はこうやって)

I know that it would mean something like : This is how (I do) ...
Yet, I cannot find the word in any dictionary. I just find the meaning of "wave height".

Comment: You are likely not parsing the sentence correctly. It is more likely that it is "... wa kō yatte" meaning "regarding..., do as such." You can find particle "wa" (は), kō, and verb yar-u in any dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it should be parsed as the `は` particle, `こう` "in this way" and `やって` (from the verb `やる` "to do").

If at the end of the sentence, I think it would most likely be "as for ..., do it in this way", but if in the middle or start of the sentence, `こうやって` can be translated as "thus" or "in this way", for example:

> こうやって私はその機械を作った。
>   I made the machine in this way.

Comment: Ok thank you !
Sorry, I didn't know that the words before this はこう were part of the sentence. Basically it is something like : [Kanji name] はこうやってかくんだよ =) (Oh I cannot Upvote yet =S)

Comment: @BabyAzerty OK no worries, in that case it means "you write ... in this way"/"you write ... like this" etc.